# SVM parameter tuning

Tags: opencv, classification, svm, emgucv, libsvm

I am newbie to using svm for classification. I want to tune svm parameters by `.TrainAuto`function in EmguCV. But I don't know what are the range(min-max value) of below parameters that I should give to this function to search:

1- C (for poly and RBF kernels)

2- Gamma (for poly and RBF kernels)

3- Coeficient (for poly kernel)

4- Degree (for poly kernel)

What are the range of these parameters?

Do these ranges depends on the number of samples?

As I receive the out of memory allocation error, can I set step parameter to a large value and when I found optimal values approximately, set these range to a smaller one and search on the second range with smaller step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should consider the RBF kernel first, unless you have a good reason not to. Here are some guides on how to choose the parameters C and gamma:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html

Comment: Tnx alot! I'm reading them. but I tested RBF and linear kernels (I don't know that the test was correct or not I'm reading your link to know) so I decided to test poly kernel.

Comment: @EYx: The linear SVM will be much faster than all the kernel versions, but will only work when your data is more or less linearly separable. So if you can get it to work for you, great, otherwise try RBF.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell that RBF and linear, both gave me weak reponce!